# how can i put appwidget on my view and let it updated itself?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

how can i put appwidget on my view and let it updated itself??now,i can put the remoteviews on my activity,but it seems not update itself, how can i make it update itself?

Comment: Is it calling onUpdate() method? Can you put logs and check it?

Comment: hi vinay,i mean i get all app widget from AppWidgetManager to show on my view, the problem is that they don't update by themselves,not create the new widget by myself, so i needn't to put log on onUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

It won't "update itself". You need to get a fresh `RemoteViews` whenever you want to update it, by whatever means you got your first `RemoteViews`.

Comment: hi,CommonsWare.you mean, i have to make a new thread to fresh the remoteViews by loop every time?

Comment: @yuankai: I don't know about the "new thread" part. And you are welcome to experiment with `AppWidgetHost` to see if you can use that to automate the updates. But just because you manually apply an app widget's `RemoteViews` does not mean it will somehow magically update itself.